# If two coordinate axes are scaled differently, do all the formulas still work?

Tags: analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates, spherical-coordinates, barycentric-coordinates

If I scale the two coordinate axes differently (e.g: two units of length to represent one unit on the y-axis whule 5 units of length to represent one unit on the x-axis), would all the formulas previously derived still apply to them? (distance formula, angle between two lines, gradient formula)

Comment: This is not clear.  What do you mean by "still work"?  Of course you can still compute the distances between points, though you will get different results post scaling.

Comment: They mostly won't work. They would yield original (not scaled) lengths, areas, angles etc. Some formulae (those to do with *ratios*) would still work, e.g. equation of the line through two points, or intersection of two lines.

Comment: Rescaling one axis will make all slope calculations need adjustment. Distance calculations will also need adjustment.

Comment: See also: [Projective geometry](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_geometry).

Comment: Look at 1800s analytic geometry books, such as Chapter VI in [**Elements of Analytic Geometry**](https://books.google.com/books?id=pywAAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA51#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Joseph Johnston Hardy (1897) and pp. 105-107 in [**Elements of Analytic Geometry**](https://archive.org/details/e00lementsofanalytwentrich/page/104/mode/2up) by George Albert Wentworth (1886).